# How to achieve autocomplete on a substring of QLineEdit in PyQt6?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, substring, qcompleter

I'm very new to QT so please assume I know nothing. I want an auto-complete where it only matches against the text after the last comma.

e.g. if my word bank is ["alpha", "beta", "vector space"], and the user currently has typed "epsilon,dog,space" then it should match against "vector space" since "space" is a substring of "vector space".

I'm using PyQt6 and my current code looks something like this (adapted from a YouTube tutorial):

```
line_of_text = QLineEdit("")
word_bank = [name for name,value in names_dict.items()]
completer = QCompleter(word_bank)
completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive)
completer.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchContains)
line_of_text.setCompleter(completer)
```

So currently, if word_bank is ["alpha", "beta", "vector space"], then if line_of_text had the string "epsilon,dog,space" then it wouldn't match against anything because "epsilon,dog,space" isn't a substring of "alpha" nor "beta" nor "vector space".

How can I alter my code to achieve what I would like to achieve? -- I'm experienced with programming, just not with Qt.

**PS:** I have tried doing

```
line_of_text.textChanged[str].connect(my_function)
```

where my_function takes only the substring of line_of_text after the last comma and feeds it to completer.setCompletionPrefix and then calls completer.complete().
This simply does not work. I assume the reason is that completer.complete() updates the completion prefix from line_of_text, causing the call to completer.setCompletionPrefix to be overwritten immediately after.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `completionModel` for `QCompleter`? You could possibly hook up `line_of_text.textChanged[str].connect` to a custom `completionModel` which will update the model with possible completions

Comment: @ElijahNicol Yes I've spent about 10 hours today viewing the docs, trying to find a solution. Wouldn't each element in the popup list of completions then necessarily contain the entire line_of_text? i.e. one autocomplete item would be "epsilon,dog,vector space" which is ugly from the user-side to see, and with a longer list of items, unusable.

Comment: It may be the case that completions have to contain the entire line_of_text - however, due to the filter mode being set to `MatchContains`, I think that the completions won't need to contain the whole line_of_text. I could totally be wrong, I haven't had time to test this myself. Are you wanting to replace the entire string with the completion? or replace just the part after the last comma?

Comment: @ElijahNicol The completions do need to contain the whole line_of_text. What MatchContains allows is for line_of_text="spa" to match the word_bank word "vector space". By default, line_of_text would have to be "v" or "ve" or "vec" or "vect",..., i.e. it'd need to start the same way. MatchContains just makes it so that it matches if line_of_text appears as a substring of the matching string. And I'm just looking to replace the part after the last comma

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the [textChanged signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html#textChanged) to set the [completion prefix](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcompleter.html#completionPrefix-prop), and bypass the built-in behaviour of the line-edit to allow greater control of when and how the completions happen.

Below is a basic implementation that shows how to do that. By default, it only shows completions when the text after the last comma has more than single character - but that can be easily adjusted:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        word_bank =  ['alpha', 'beta', 'vector space']
        self.completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(word_bank)
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(
            QtCore.Qt.CaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive)
        self.completer.setFilterMode(QtCore.Qt.MatchFlag.MatchContains)
        self.completer.setWidget(self.edit)
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.handleCompletion)
        self.edit.textChanged.connect(self.handleTextChanged)
        self._completing = False

    def handleTextChanged(self, text):
        if not self._completing:
            found = False
            prefix = text.rpartition(',')[-1]
            if len(prefix) > 1:
                self.completer.setCompletionPrefix(prefix)
                if self.completer.currentRow() >= 0:
                    found = True
            if found:
                self.completer.complete()
            else:
                self.completer.popup().hide()

    def handleCompletion(self, text):
        if not self._completing:
            self._completing = True
            prefix = self.completer.completionPrefix()
            self.edit.setText(self.edit.text()[:-len(prefix)] + text)
            self._completing = False

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 50)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming str is the string from the text input) Have you tried separating str using the , character, then iterating over each of the words separated by a comma.

```
for word in str.split(","):
     
      for check in word_bank:
           etc...
```

the connected function will be called in your case whenever the string entered changes.

Comment: I don't understand what your intended solution is. I have no control over what text the completer checks against the word_bank. It always uses the entire string contained in QLineEdit. If I could just have it check against a substring of str (the substring after the final comma), the solution would be easy.